# How to mimic CheckboxBar's Method->"Active" option in a Manipulate's checkbox control?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, eventhandler

`CheckboxBar` has a `Method -> "Active"` option that allows you to click the label to change the state of a checkbox.  I would like to implement this for `Checkbox` controls in `Manipulate`.

My attempt was to place an `EventHandler` (`MouseClicked`) on the label of the checkbox that would update the dynamic variable (`check`).

```
Manipulate[
 check,
 {{check, True, 
   EventHandler["Use this", {"MouseClicked" :> (check = Not@check;)}]}, Checkbox}]
```

However, I am getting a recursion limit error on click.

> $RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of !check. >>

Ideas?

---

**Update: Could be a bug**

I'm beginning to think that this is a bug in `Manipulate` because the method works outside of `Manipulate`.  This works as expected:

```
check = True;
Row[{
  EventHandler["Use this ", {"MouseClicked" :> (check = Not@check;)}],
  Checkbox[Dynamic@check]
  }]
```

Clicking either the label or the `Checkbox` results in `check` being updated with no recursion limit issues.

Can anyone else confirm this?

10.3 Win 7 Pro 64bit

Comment: Wrapping `EventHandler` with `Dynamic` (i.e. `Manipulate[check, {{check, True,
Dynamic@EventHandler[
"Use this", {"MouseClicked" :> (check = Not@check;)}]}, Checkbox}]`) seems to work?

Comment: @kglr Any idea why `Dynamic` is needed for this not to enter a recursive loop? It still feels like a bug.

Comment: i am not sure why.

Comment: Reported to WRI to see if it is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Work-arounds.

kglr

```
Manipulate[
  check, 
  {{check, 
    True, 
    Dynamic @ 
      EventHandler["Click here", {"MouseClicked" :> (check = Not @ check)}]}, 
   Checkbox}]
```

m_goldberg

```
Manipulate[check,
  {{check,
   True,
   Dynamic[ClickPane["Click here", (check = Not @ check)&]]},
  Checkbox}]
```